# Get value of a function created from array without using index

Tags: matlab, function

Let's consider the following script where I am creating a function such as `y = f(x)`:

```
x = 0:0.01:2;
y = 0:0.02:4;
figure(1);clf;
plot(x, y);
```

Let's say I would now like to get some values of f such as f(0.5), f(1) or f(1.5). Is there any ways to get those values with a matlab function or do I have to first get the index of 0.5, 1 and 1.5 in x in order to get f(x)?

Comment: there are several ways, you can either evaluate it for f(0.5) f(1) etc if you have the function, or you can estimate it by estimating on the plot, or you can estimate it via interpolation. depends on what you are looking for really

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have an actual function, you can call it like `f(x)`...

```
f = @(xi) 2.*xi;

f(0.5)    % >> ans = 1
f(0.5001) % >> ans = 1.0002
f(10)     % >> ans = 20
```

If you have two corresponding arrays like in your example code, you can use indexing of the `x` data

```
x = 0:0.01:2;
y = 0:0.02:4;

y(x==0.5)    % >> ans = 1
y(x==0.5001) % >> ans = []
y(x==10)     % >> ans = []
```

If you have the second case, but want to interpolate to avoid the `y(x==0.5001)=[]` result, you can set up a function like so

```
x = 0:0.01:2;
y = 0:0.02:4;
f = @(xi) interp1( x, y, xi );

f(0.5)    % >> ans = 1
f(0.5001) % >> ans = 1.0002
f(10)     % >> NaN
```